# Как сделать такие же пункты как на скрине?

Tags: c#, winapi

Как сделать такие же пункты как на скрине?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта фича называется *Jump List*. Пример можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36561/Windows-7-Goodies-in-C-Jump-Lists).